# Pausing individual spiders in a CrawlerProcess

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm currently working on a project that involves crawling data from various (about 50 websites). There is one website which has multiple pages we need to scrape, but this website doesn't allow multiple session. (the website is authenticated).

Is there a way to pause the one spider until the other one is finished?

I've been researching this for the past day. I found some ways you can pause, but it seems these are only working for the whole CrawlerProcess.

Comment: You say you have a website that does not allow concurrent requests, and because of that you want to pause some spiders. Does that mean that you are using several different spiders for the same website? Have you tried using `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN`?

Comment: As @Gallaecio pointed out the easiest approach would be to set `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` setting to 1 for that particular domain. If you would share your spider code (where you use `CrawlerProcess`) we could help you out.

Comment: There is indeed more than one Spider for one website, @Gallaecio . The project is about scraping data from brands. There is a spider for every brand, but in this case, one website has multiple brands.

Comment: Why do you use separate spiders per brand? How different are those spiders from each other?

Comment: Most of the brands have their own website, so they are completely different, but these particular two brands are on the same website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually fairly easy. Each spider has a unique identifying code. When setting the CrawlerProcess up, the program checks if the unique code is the same as the one that needs pausing, and if so, it passes the spider instance to the spider that needs to run first, which will then pause it with `self.custom_settings['XX_SPIDER'].crawler.pause()` and when done, in the `closed()` function, will unpause it with `self.custom_settings['XX_SPIDER'].crawler.unpause()`